# Persistence error in JPA

Tags: jpa

I am creating a small JPA project.

But I am receiving the below error, when I run the main class.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ClientAccount
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:56)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
at com.infinite.ClientAccountMain.main(ClientAccountMain.java:12)
```

the name in the persistence unit is the same used in the entity manager factory

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ClientAccount");

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ClientAccount">
<description>My Persistence Unit</description>

<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.infinite.Order</class>
 <class>com.infinite.Account</class>
   <class>com.infinite.Client</class>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

 <properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=testdatabase" />
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
 </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: The call looks OK. Check whether the persistence.xml is actually present in a META-INF directory on the classpath. See the documentation on possible locations of persistence files.

Comment: I'm sure you'd get a perfectly good answer by just searching for "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named"

Comment: Not enough research made, just search for the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Neil Stockton is right and if you search a bit you will find your answer. Although I think that must be something in relation with your provider information.

Try to put something like this.

For OpenJPA

```
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
```

Source information ---> http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-
1.0.3/docs/manual/jpa_overview_persistence.html

For Hibernate

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple causes for this error:

1. You do not have the specified JPA provider on your classpath (check the JARs).
2. You did not define the persistence unit in your `persistence.xml` file.
3. Your persistence provider did not find your `persistence.xml` file (usually it is in `META-INF/persistence.xml`). Check that it is on the right place.